# Monoid diagram and "identity morphism is unique"

Tags: javascript, categories, monoids

In Category theory: Monoid topic, I often observe explanation like this:

[image]

[image]

http://yogsototh.github.io/Category-Theory-Presentation/categories.html#slide-28

[image]

http://bitterharvest.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/04/18/133250

However, I understand **identity morphism is unique**.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Identity_Morphism_is_Unique

So, I guess providing an image multiple identity morphisms on the identical object is inappropriate.

If I'm wrong, what do I miss?? Thanks.

**EDIT with a JavaScript code:**

```js
  // a is a singleton (any category with a single object)
  const identity = a => a;
  // identity morphism is unique on the cateogory
  console.log(
    identity("")  // "" is identity of Strings
      + identity("H")
      + identity("e")
      + identity("l")
      + identity("l")
      + identity("o")
  );
```

Comment: I don't understand what's the question. The images above only show one identity morphism (and many non-identity morphisms). What's wrong with that?

Comment: @chi How can a mofphism not be identity when the moprphism loops back to itself?

Comment: The identity is a morphism form an object to itself, but a morphism from an object to itself does not have to be the identity. For instance, in the Set category (ob=sets, hom=functions), there are functions from the set of natural numbers to itself which are not the identity function (e.g. `\x -> x+3`). In your picture above `""` is the identity (since `"" ++ x == x ++ "" == x`), but `ab` is not (e.g. `"ab" ++ "c" /= "c"`).

Comment: @chi The morphism from an obj in the category of natural numbers to another obj in the identical category of natural numbers is an endofunctor, but the function/morhism `\x -> x+3`  is not an identity morphism. `\x -> x` is the only identity function in the category.

Comment: I think this question belongs on either https://math.stackexchange.com or https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @chi I missed to have mentioned, what you are saying is identity functor that is the simplest endofunctor.

Comment: @smooth_writing No, you are thinking of more complex constructions. Think of the set category. The set N is an object there. You can find many morphisms (=functions) from N to N, beyond the identity. No functors involved, and no need to regard N as a category for this example.

Comment: @chi Thanks for your continual reply. Please review my **EDIT with a JavaScript code:** in my question. I think I understand what you explain, and having said that I still think it's not appropriate to have multiple "identity morphism" because, again, it should be unique.

Comment: The identity _is_ unique. The other morphisms are _not_ the identity, even if they have the same source and target object. You think that "identity" and "endomorphism" are the same notion, but they are not.

Answer (score 1):

The identity morphism on object `A`, is a special morphism that is `A -> A` but, and this is what restricts it so much, it ALSO has to fulfill the **IDENTITY LAW**:

```
for any morphism f : A -> A,

idA . f = f . idA
```

Most morphisms `notIdA : A -> A` will not fulfill this requirement. But `idA` will.

Comment: btw, the set of all morphisms `A -> A` is called `Hom(A, A)`, and it contains `idA`.